# SQL command to change all page with one page_template to another

Tags: sql, wordpress

I need to change all the pages in a 3000+ page WP site which have a specific _wp_page_template back to the default template. I'm not a sql guy, but know my way around phpMyAdmin and know how to execute query/commands, just need a little help writing it. I've googled my face off, and I know this can't be difficult, just don't want to cock it up and have to db restore. I'm backed up and ready to go, just need to know how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value`='default'
WHERE `meta_key`='_wp_page_template' AND `meta_value`='your-page-template.php';
```

This will affect all the pages that have `your-page-template.php` template, assuming your table has the default name `wp_postmeta`.

If you want to try first this change on a few pages you can add a limit:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value`='default'
WHERE `meta_key`='_wp_page_template' AND `meta_value`='your-page-template.php'
LIMIT 5;
```

This will affect only the first 5 pages of the result, easier to roll back if something goes not as expected.

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly, you're setting ALL pages back to "default", I need to set only pages that currently have the 'meta_value' of 'page-templates/right-sidebar.php' ... is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: ok you didn't specify that in your question... i'm gonna edit my aswer accordingly

Comment: Sorry, first tine I've posted a question here. Thanks for the guidance.